# Python detect string and int using exception handling

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to work on detecting strings and int using exception handling and cannot figure it out. Please help!

Using the inputs

- Lee 18
- Lua 21
- Mary Beth 19
- Stu 33
- -1

```
    parts = input().split()
    name = parts[0]

    while name != '-1':

    # FIXME: The following line will throw ValueError exception.
    #        Insert try/except blocks to catch the exception.
    try:
        age = int(parts[1]) + 1
        print('{} {}'.format(name, age))
        parts = input().split()
        name = parts[0]
        if age != 0:
            raise ValueError(0)
    except ValueError as excpt:
        name = parts[0]
        age = excpt
```

The result of the code above is:

- Lee 19
- Lua 22
- 

When I am trying to get the code to result with:

- Lee 19
- Lua 22
- Mary 0
- Stu 34

Please assist!

Comment: Try using a "Regular Expression".

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out messing with it for a while solution code

```
# Split input into 2 parts: name and age
parts = input().split()
name = parts[0]
while name != '-1':
    # FIXME: The following line will throw ValueError exception.
    #        Insert try/except blocks to catch the exception.
    try:
        age = int(parts[1]) + 1
        print('{} {}'.format(name, age))
        parts = input().split()
        name = parts[0]
        if age == 'Beth':
            age = 0
            
    except ValueError as excpt:
        age = 0
        print('{} {}'.format(name, age))
        parts = input().split()
        name = parts[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    age = int(parts[1]) + 1
    print('{} {}'.format(name, age))
    parts = input().split()
    name = parts[0]
        
except ValueError as excpt:
    age = 0
    print('{} {}'.format(name, age))
    parts = input().split()
    name = parts[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here so far have too much code. I think the lab wants a "finally" statement.

```
parts = input().split()
name = parts[0]
while name != '-1':
    try:
        age = int(parts[1]) + 1
    except ValueError:
        age = 0
    finally:
        print('{} {}'.format(name, age))
        parts = input().split()
        name = parts[0]
```

That way it's explicit that age always gets defined and printed. Although you can get away without the 'finally':

```
parts = input().split()
name = parts[0]
while name != '-1':
    try:
        age = int(parts[1]) + 1
    except ValueError:
        age = 0
    print('{} {}'.format(name, age))
    parts = input().split()
    name = parts[0]
```

Basically instead of identifying the ValueError, we're just assigning age with 0 and continuing on. This is essentially working as an if/else. If age isn't an integer, then assign age with 0. Then it jumps to the next line of code and loops until input is -1.

I just did this lab 5 minutes ago and both of these get graded 10/10.

Answer (score 0):

```
parts = input().split()
name = parts[0]
while name != '-1':
    # FIXME: The following line will throw ValueError exception.
    #        Insert try/except blocks to catch the exception.
    try:
        age = int(parts[1]) + 1
        print(f'{name} {age}')
    except ValueError:
        age = 0
        print(f'{name} {age}')
    
    # Get next line
    parts = input().split()
    name = parts[0]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).